# repetitive noise filter of an image in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab-guide

Good evening, I require some help with the following image processing in Matlab:

By designing a suppressive band filter in the frequency domain lascomponentes remove periodic noise and try to identify the license plate number of the car and details of the face of the person driving it. You should display spectra of magnitude and phase of the original and filtered image. It is suggested to remove the current peaks present in the spectrum magnitude that contaminate image signal varying dimension frequencies remuevan spectral noise for an appropriate solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6nCg.jpg)

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Cvt.png)
[image]

--To Remove noise from the image, I am using notch filters Butterworth type, but not cutting frequencies on which the image is properly filtered

can someone help me to discover how is the pattern noise in the magnitude spectrum of the image, and cuts frequencies and filters are suitable for every point of energy?

Comment: you can find an answer for This question using Python on Webpage [link](https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/)
just search for **halftone** to find your answer

Answer (score 0):

Please trythis code to automatically detecting and diffusing noisy sinuzoidal functions

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
org=im2double(imread('halftone.png'));
aaa=lfdf(org);
figure,imshow(aaa);
```

The function lfdf can be downloaded from 
https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/74143-lfdf